# Cosine law derivative assistance needed

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives

I read the wiki, but I would really appreciate it if someone can explain it to me and help me solve it; I don't know how to do it. By no means is this HW.

> #### Derivative Cosine law
>
> Given a planar triangle $[v_i,v_j,v_k]$, suppose the edges against vertex $v_i$, $v_j$ and $v_k$ are with lengths $l_i$, $l_j$, and $l_k$. The corner angles at $v_i$, $v_j$ and $v_k$ are $\theta_i$, $\theta_j$ and $\theta_k$. We can treat the angles as the functions of the edge lengths. Compute
>   $$\frac{\partial\theta_i(l_i,l_j,l_k)}{\partial l_i}-\frac{\partial\theta_i(l_i,l_j,l_k)}{\partial l_j}-\frac{\partial\theta_i(l_i,l_j,l_k)}{\partial l_k}.$$

Comment: I had a lot of trouble reading the quantity you are supposed to calculate. Please verify that I have written it correctly. In the future, please read the tag summary before adding a tag. This question has absolutely nothing to do with general topology or with graph theory.

Comment: @dfeuer it is correct

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**: The title contains the hint, it's the cosine law

$$l_k^2=l^2_i+l^2_j-2l_i l_j \cos(\theta_k)$$

**EDIT**: Take the derivative w.r.t. $l_i$ for instance and you'll get:

$$0=2l_i-2 l_j \cos(\theta_k)+2l_i l_j \sin(\theta_k)\frac{\partial\theta_k}{\partial l_i}$$

or after rearranging

$$\frac{\partial\theta_k}{\partial l_i}=\frac{l_j \cos(\theta_k)-l_i}{l_il_j\sin(\theta_k)}$$

Using the cosine law again, it's possible to express this only in function of the lengths. You can work out the other derivatives in a similar fashion.

Comment: can you explain? Thats the answer above?

Comment: Nope, it's not the end answer, just a hint to help you on the way. Can you do implicit derivation?

Comment: I vaguely recall it, so the implicit derivation of that l^2subk that you posted is the answer to my problem? Please elaborate

Comment: @Turkistan, why don't you start by taking the partial derivative of the law of cosines for $\theta_i$ with respect to each variable and see if you come up with anything that looks like it might be useful?